# Angular: *ngFor array of strings, remove '/' symbol

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a ngFor loop that loops an array of strings `sideBarRoutesPath`.

```
       <div class="sidebar-feature" *ngFor = "let side of sideBarRoutesPath">
          <button mat-button color="primary" class="feature-button">
            {{side}}
          </button>

        </div>
```

**What I want to do:**
Right now, my `{{side}}` displays the strings correctly.  However, the strings contain `'/'` in them, but I don't want the `'/'` symbol when it gets displayed on my HTML.

```
["/devices/", "/account/overview"]
```

I don't want to remove the `'/'`'s in the string array itself because I need the `'/'` for routing purposes.  So I'm thinking I have to create a second array that copies my first array and then removes the `/` OR do it in the `*ngFor` somehow with regex.

I tried: `sideBarRoutesPath.replace(/\W/g, '')`  which eliminates the '/' but then it mashes all the strings together, so that didn't work.

Comment: I don't want the '/' symbol. I don't want to remove the '/'. what do you want then

Comment: I don't want to remove the '/' in the array, so I'm guessing I have to create a second array that doesn't have the '/' or maybe there's a regex in angular that gets rid of it?

Comment: can't you just replace them with a space `sideBarRoutesPath.replace(/\W/g,' ')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a method in the component class to remove the `/` characters:

```
public removeSlashes(side: string): string {
    return side.replace(/\//g, "");
}
```

and call it in the template:

```
{{ removeSlashes(side) }}
```